# How to store a list of KFunction1 for kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin

Basically I want to create a router that can be used in the following way

```
router.register(someInstance::getData)
router.register(someInstance::submitData)
```

where both getData and submitData is an instance of

```
getParam : KFunction1<GetParam, GetResponse> 
submitData : KFunction1<SubmitParam, SubmitResponse>
```

where GetParam, GetResponse, SubmitParam, SubmitResponse is a class that implements respective interfaces (IParam, IResponse)

inside the register it would look like

```
val routeMap = mutableMapOf<String, KFunction1<IParam, IResponse>
fun register<P : IParam, R : IResponse>(func : KFunction1<P, R>) {
    routeMap["abc"] = func
}
```

only problem right now is that it seems that I can't access KFunction1 directly (so I cannot store them)

the idea is to basically create some sort of router that can register and call the registered functions later on. If anyone has any other idea on how to implement this, feel free to give suggestions

Comment: What do you mean by `I can't access KFunction1 directly`?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to register and call them, use the normal function types: `(P) -> R`, not `KFunction1<P, R>`.

But the real issue is that `(P) -> R` is not a subtype of `(IParam) -> IResponse` (and can't be because its `invoke` method doesn't accept any `IParam`) and so can't be stored in `routeMap`.

How to fix this will depend on what you want to happen when types don't match.